# calling a console application from a command prompt

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, console-application, exe

I have created a new console application using visual studio 2012 . Then I navigate to the following location inside my project "...\bin\debug" and I copy the .exe file to the C.
Now I want to call this .exe file from the command prompt , so I wrote the following :-

```
C:\>ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

but I get the following error :-

```
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here is my console application main method:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SkillManagementEntities sd = new SkillManagementEntities())
            {
                sd.Levels.Add(new Level() { Name = "from CA" });
                sd.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and if I open the .exe file using notepad I will get the following where it contains configuration rather than the actual method code...:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SkillManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=SkillManagement;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

This is the file I copied :-

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a command prompt and not a powershell prompt?  Try: `.\ConsoleApplication1.exe` instead.

Comment: Are you sure that you have copied the EXE and not the EXE.CONFIG file? (watch about [hide well known file extension](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7) configuration)

Comment: @CodingGorilla yes I am using CMD not powershell

Comment: Type `C:\>dir` and check if `ConsoleApplication1.exe` is in the list

Comment: @MattBurland I have a file named ConsoleApplication1.exe directly on the c drive...

Comment: @steve now when I navigate inside my application \bin\debug there are onlt one file with .exe and it has its type as XML configuration file

Comment: "*if I open the .exe file using notepad I will get the following , where it contain configuration rather than the actual method code*": Look at the title bar in notepad. What does it say? I'm betting, as others have suggested, it'll say `ConsoleApplication1.exe.config`

Comment: @MattBurland no it says ConsoleApplication1.exe ,, can you check my question again I provided the files that I have , and I marked the one I have copied

Comment: @JohnJohn: You check again, because you have very clearly copied the *wrong file*. And the title bar in notepad will have `.exe.config`. Look at the one with the type "Application". That's your exe file. You are hiding extensions (which is a really annoying "feature" of Windows IMHO)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis but seems the .exe file only contain configuration data, not the actual code

Comment: @MattBurland thanks for the help..  so you mean I need to copy the "ClickOnce Application" into my c drive and call it from CMD ?

Comment: Second file from the top. That's your EXE

Comment: @JohnJohn: I misspoke at first. You need the one with the type "application". That is `ConsoleApplication1.exe`, it's just that windows explorer is hiding the extension. You with *also* need that config file in the *same directory* if you want the thing to actually work. As well as the entity framework files too. So really, it would probably be easier to to run it from the folder and not try to move it to the C drive in the first place.

Comment: Here's a useful tip, in Windows Explorer, in the tree-view, navigate to your debug folder and when *hold shift and right-click* the `debug` folder. Then select "Open command window here". This will give you a command prompt already set to the directory with your files. Now you don't need to mess around with copying anything. Just type `ConsoleApplication1` and it should run

Comment: @MattBurland now if I run the .application file directly from my project it will work,, but if I copy it to the c drive then I run it , I will get an error "nhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c5
61934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
.
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)",, so not sure what I need to do as I want to move the application file to another server..

Comment: @JohnJohn That's a separate issue, please do not move the goal posts. Since this is resolved, I'd recommend accepting gmiley's answer.

Comment: You should probably also check your folder options [here](http://imgur.com/dprzKzU). Uncheck the box to hide known extensions. As for not running from the C drive, as I said, you'll probably need to copy all the other dependencies too (e.g. Entity Framework)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely have your file extensions hidden, which means you also likely copied `ConsoleApplication1.exe.config` instead of `ConsoleApplication1.exe`, however you should have both present in the folder where you want to execute the program from. When you copied it, you may copied `ConsoleApplication1.exe.config` to `ConsoleApplication1.exe`, accidentally dropping the original .config extension.

Comment: no I copied the .exe file ,, can you check my question again I provided an image showing the files that I have inside the \bin\debug folder, and I marked the one I have copied

Comment: @JohnJohn No, you didn't. Look at the screenshot. It says specifically that it's a XML Configuration File meaning that's your `.exe.config`, not your `.exe`. The `.config` extension is hidden. Go to Folder Options -> View and uncheck `Hide extensions for known file types`

Comment: @gmiley now I want to move the .application file to another server,, so which file I need to copy , because if I run the .application file directly from my project folder it will work,, but if I copy it to the c drive then I run it , I will get an error "unhandled exception.. system.io.filenotfound could not load file or assembly 'Entity framework",, so not sure what I need to do as I want to move the .application file to another server..

Comment: @JohnJohn That's a separate issue, please do not move the goal posts. Since this is resolved, I'd recommend accepting this answer.

Comment: @JohnJohn: Copy `EntityFramework.dll` too and possibility other files.

Comment: @MattBurland I ended up copying these 4 files:- EF.dll & EF.xml & .exe &.config files,, now I can run the .exe file correctly,, but not sure if this is the right way of deploying a console application ?